# Force EndpointNotFoundException raise from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

We have an existing WCF client that receives data from a WCF service. We have one specific business logic implemented in client side that will execute only if EndpointNotFoundException found from WCF call. Recently we received a very specific requirement where the same logic needs to be executed for some special business scenario. However, due to business constraint, we dont have flexibility to modify code in client side. Hence, we started thinking that if it is possible to raise force EndpointNotFoundException from service so that same code can be executed in client if EndpointNotFoundException received from service. Problem is, WCF service always send a fault contract exception even we raise EndpointNotFoundException from service. My question is, is there any way to raise EndpointNotFoundException from service so that client can receive exact same error instead any fault exception.

Your inputs will be highly appreciated. This is very critical from business point of view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, if I set the status code of the request as 404 not found, ultimately at client end it will throw as EndpointNotFoundException exception.If the request has processed successfully.

```
WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
```